# WP_Query not Working if Taxonomy Term has Single Quotes

Tags: taxonomy, wordpress

I'm using `WP_Query` to [retrieve posts based on certain taxonomy terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).  The problem is that `WP_Query` is not returning any results if the term has a single quote.

Here's the relevant portion of the args passed to WP_Query:

```
[tax_query] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [taxonomy] => country
                [field] => name
                [terms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => People's Republic of China
                    )

            )

    )
```

I tried escaping the quote `(e.g. People\'s Republic of China)` but still there are no results.

There is no problem with the code as other terms without the quote work.  And if you ask, there are posts with the single quotes as validated from directly querying from the database (via phpmyadmin).

I know that I can just query using taxonomy id and slug (e.g. `'field'=>'term_id'` AND  `'field'=>'slug'`) but I hope not to as too may code has been written to use the term name.

Thanks

Comment: where is the code of `WP_QUERY` ? `$args` array ? also how do you get the taxonomy, please add php code.

Comment: See the following [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180651/escaping-wp-query-tax-query-when-term-has-special-characters)

Comment: This should have been resolved few months ago, are you sure that your Wordpress installation is up to date?

Comment: I see @AnandShah has already linked back to my answer about using term names. In short, use `get_term_by` or rather use the term slug or ID

Comment: @Noman Sorry I didn't paste the php code as I was a bit rushed. But basically it's just passing the correct array format to the standard WP_Query Wordpress object, and not really a PHP issue.

Comment: Sorry @Anand but I have to give Pieter the credit.  Appreciate the quick response though and have upvoted(?) your comment

Comment: @Pieter Thanks for the in-depth investigation you've done on this issue.  Please post an answer so that I can accept it, even if it's a link back to your original answer.

Comment: @vard. Oops you're right. I'm using 4.2.5 when 4.3.1 is already available.  Broke the cardinal rule of not updating to the latest WP version.  Thanks!

Comment: No need to be sorry :) By all means the credit must and should go to @PieterGoosen

Comment: FYI.  I just upgraded to the latest version 4.3..1.  Unfortunately problem persists.